# GSM Modem Send Message in UCS2 format error

Tags: java, gsm, at-command

I'm using java to communicate with a gsm modem (Siemens) using AT commands.
I set the encoding of modem to "UCS2".
When sending messages as soon as I send the phone number I get ERROR from the device:

AT+CSCS=UCS2
OK

AT+CSMP=17,167,0,8
OK

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CMGS="0919xxxxxxx"
ERROR

HELP ME, PLEEEEEEASE! :(

Comment: what the AT+CSCS=? command replies? Also the phone number shouldn't have the country code with the '+' symbol?

Comment: +CSCS: ("GSM","UCS2")
I tested both ways 91 style (+9xxx...) and 92 (09xx...).

Comment: try with AT+CSCS="UCS2" instead of AT+CSCS=UCS2. I think it accept the command but is not a valid value without the quotes, so it gives error when you try to send with CMGS

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still get ERROR, but I had to switch to sending sms in PDU format and it's working...

Comment: Then add this as answer and mark as answered :)

Comment: But this is not the solution! The problem is probably with my GSM modem; because I've seen a lot of samples on the internet using "UCS2" (or "HEX") and text mode and they did not report any issues. (So switching to PDU mode do not solve this problem!) :)

Comment: It is very possible that your modem doesn't not support the CMGS with UCS2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are encoding the `<da>` address argument to `AT+CMGS` incorrectly.

You refer to 91 and 92 style, but are you actually referring to the '81'/'82' format as explained in the [Coding of Alpha fields in the SIM for UCS2](http://d-chips.blogspot.com/2012/06/coding-of-alpha-fields-in-sim-for-ucs2.html) blog post about encoding as specified in [3GPP TS 11.11](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/1111.htm)?

After you run `AT+CSCS="UCS2"` every single string must be encoded that way, so for instance to switch from UCS2 to UTF-8 would be `AT+CSCS="005500540046002D0038"`.

Alpha fields with 80/81/82 encoding only applies to some cases, and not UCS2 encoded strings in general. In particular notice that the encoding of the string "UTF-8" in the above `AT+CSCS` command has nothing to do with this. That also applies to the `<da>` argument to `AT+CMGS`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that your modem does not support the CMGS with UCS2.