# Running USSD command on GSM modem (wrong Encoding maybe)

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, ussd

I am trying to execute USSD command using GSM modem.

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*200#",15
```

and the result I get is not readable

> "+CUSD:
>   0,"Æ·ÜNÓu9XŽt�¤å1:,?—u0Œt�ši7è,Óëizy®ƒ5ÓnÔL»Ai7½,w‡éé·;Ì.ÏAòòœvÓËs�ÖL»",15"

when I try the same ussd code on the mobile phone using the same sim I get a correct result which is

> "Forfait: 909DA. Recharchege:0.0DA Min gratuites: 0Min. Min
>   internationales restantes :0Min"

changing the character set  AT+CSCS from GSM to IRA or PCCP, PCDN, 8859-1 doesnt change the response it is the same response exactly

and changing  AT+CSCS to hex gives me an error :

```
AT+CSCS="HEX"
AT+CUSD=1,"*200#",15 

OK
+CUSD: 2,"Unexpected Data Value",15
+CUSD: 2,"Unexpected Data Value",15
ERROR
```

and changing it to UCS2 and calling the USSD make my modem reboot

```
AT+CSCS="UCS2"
AT+CUSD=1,"*200#",15
```

Comment: The two Unexpected Data Value errors are for the `* ` and `#` characters because they are not hexadecimal characters. When changing character encoding with AT+CSCS it applies to **all** strings following as I mentioned in my answer. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18672278/23118) for an example setting UTF-8 with UCS2 encoding active. The same error applies in the second case with UCS2, although the behaviour of rebooting is not as nice as printing a helpful "Unexpected Data Value" error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AT+CUSD` command is specified in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) and the format of the unsolicited result code is defined as `+CUSD: <m>[,<str>,<dcs>]`.

From your received response you can see that `<m>` is `0` and `<dcs>` is `15` in addition to the gibberish for `<str>` which by the way does not simply map directly to the `AT+CSCS` character encoding; there is a whole section devoted to explaining its presentation that you must look further into.

Looking up the 23.038 standard referenced in 27.007 the `<dcs>` value 15 maps to *Language unspecified* but reading the text above it also seems to be identical with *GSM 7 bit default alphabet*.

So yes, your suspicion about encoding problems is correct and unfortunately the standards are not very intuitive for this, you have to dive in deeply.

For debugging this I would start by setting `AT+CSCS="HEX"` and verify that the received data makes sense when decoded, and then work on either getting it presented in a usable format or possibly decoding it explicitly from hex in software yourself (but be aware that changing `AT+CSCS` then applies to all strings from then on, including the `<chset>` parameter of `AT+CSCS` when you want to change encoding to something else later on...)

Comment: First, thanks for the a very helpful response. I start to think that the ,<str> is encrypted can that be possible ? because I tried feeding the gibberish I got in response into a GSM 7bit decoder but with no luck. nothing resembling a clear message was found.

Answer (score 0):

AT+CMGF=0

AT+CSCS=HEX

AT+CUSD=1,"*123#", 15

get the result and convert the ussd pdu to text

python lib : 
https://pypi.org/project/PDUUSSDConverter/

straight answer . good luck